# Passing a variable in iFrame source in php

Tags: php, iframe

I am trying to open a url in iFrame,

However I can't seems to properly pass $url in iFrame src=?

```
function Payment() 
{       
    $userId     = trim($_REQUEST['userId']);
    $venueId    = trim($_REQUEST['venueId']);
    $amount     = trim($_REQUEST['amount']);
    $quantity   = trim($_REQUEST['quantity']);
    $order      = trim($_REQUEST['order']);

    $url = "https://direct.tranzila.com/weenxmobile/mobile.php?sum=".$quantity."&currency=".$amount;

    //open $url in iframe <?php echo $url; "  <iframe src="<?php echo $url; width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
    ?>
        <iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
    <?php
}
```

It opens page, but the submit buttons gives me "System Error" However if i edit this code and simple put url inside iframe source , it works just fine.

Comment: You don't seem to be *trying* to pass it.

Comment: @Quentin i tried and it didn't work well? how to do is was my qyestion

Comment: @Quentin please check my edited code, i have placed the sample url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simple:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
```

(don't forget to escape it properly)

Comment: if i do this then processing this page gives system Error.

Comment: @Quentin "System error" Its actually a payment portal and when i do open it this way it gives system error on Submit Button" However when i simply do <iframe src="http:xxx" then it works just fine

Comment: So the third party site gives you the error? How does the generated source compare to the working source?

Comment: @Quentin please check the edited version, if i replace the "<?php echo $url; ?>" with simple url it works fine

Comment: Try `echo $url` and paste your "static" url below it, I don't believe it's identical.

Comment: @PavelŠtěrba AH U are right, the query was passing a nil variable quantity :).... That was quite stupid i did wrong in my origianl url in my app, some spell mistake. I thought its some coding problem in php :) thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    //open $url in iframe <?php echo $url; "  <iframe src="<?php echo $url; width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
> ```

You omitted the second `"` from the src attribute value.

This would have been picked up if you had use [a markup validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: When i use this code src="<?php echo $url; ?>" it GIVES ME SYSTEM ERROR. However if i just embed the url as <iframe src="www.placeaboveurlhere.com"> it works fine and gives no error on submit button. You can try urself.

Comment: I can't try myself. You keep changing your mind about what your code actually is and you haven't told us what the input it. Show us the manually written HTML that works. Show us the HTML you generate from PHP that doesn't work (the HTML! not just the PHP!). In both cases, show the complete start tag for the iframe element.